# Working with ContextMenu in android

Tags: android

I have wrote the following code to write simple `ContextMenu` example in android. In this example I tried `edit` and `delete` option. But the problem is I could not find the correct row to edit. Eg: If I long click the 5th row's `edit` menu the `Layout` vissible in nth row. I dont what is wrong. Also I don't how to achieve this. I tried this way.

```
public class ContextMenuActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contextmenu);
        initComponents();
        setActionListener();
    }

     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
     ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
     }

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        // info.position will give the index of selected item
        int IndexSelected = info.position;
        if (item.getTitle() == "Edit") {
            View v1 = list.getAdapter().getView(IndexSelected, list, null);
            mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
            mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.listitem_txt_item);
            Button b = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.myButton3);
            final EditText et = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.myEditText3);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
                    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi edit " + IndexSelected,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Code to execute when clicked on This Item
        } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi delete ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // alistItems.remove(adapter.getItem(IndexSelected));

        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        inflater = ContextMenuActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contextmenu_lst_list);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listitem_txt_item);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
        alistItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (loopCount = 1; loopCount < 30; loopCount++) {
            alistItems.add("Item " + loopCount);
        }
        prepareView();
    }

    CustomAdapter adapter;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ListView list;
    TextView tv;
    ArrayList<String> alistItems;
    int loopCount;

    private void prepareView() {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listitem,
                alistItems);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }

    private void setActionListener() {
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

            }
        });
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        ArrayList<String> alistItems;
        int resource;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                ArrayList<String> alistItems) {
            super(context, resource);
            this.alistItems = alistItems;
            this.resource = resource;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return alistItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
            }
            holder.tvRow = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitem_txt_item);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.tvRow.setText(alistItems.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView tvRow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
 // global variable
Object item;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    Adapter adapter = getListAdapter();
    item = adapter.getItem(info.position);

 menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");

}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit") {
        edit(item.getItemId());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

public void edit(int id) {

Object IndexSelected = item;

// your code for edit


}
```

It works for me.

Comment: In the edit function you have to write the code what you do when the user clicks on "Edit" in the ContextMenu. Actually what you wrote above. This solution should work, because it does for me. You have to fix the errors for yourself I can't do this for you. This line: adapter.getItem(info.position); gives you the String of the listItmem you had clicked.

Comment: of course you have to change your code a bit to fit it with my solution. And it's just a suggestion, you don't have to use it if you don't want. Maybe try to debug your solution and see what you retrieve and why that is wrong.

Comment: I cant add `AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    Adapter adapter = getListAdapter();
    item = adapter.getItem(info.position);` these lines into `onCreateContextMenu`.

Comment: Do you have this import? `import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;`

Comment: Yes. If I added these lines then While clicking list item I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid Index 3, Size is 0` this error